# Generate PDF using Javascript (Client side) with header and footer

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is there any client-side Javascript framework to generate pdf with header and footer from Html content, like some fixed footer on all pages (page 1 of 10).

we tried with [html2pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js) but it does not have the ability to add header and footer. is there any similar client-side javascript libraries available with header and footer option to generate pdf?.

Comment: I just glanced over the link you provided for the GitHub. From there I google searched "html2pdf headers and footers". A dozen links came up with examples. Here is one of such links: https://haensel.pro/allgemein/jspdf-html2pdf-loop-through-pages-and-add-content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use jsPDF for this job, more details about this framework is available in this link of Github:https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF
and for adding the footer and header you can use this library with a callback function to html2pdf. more details and source code are available in :
https://haensel.pro/allgemein/jspdf-html2pdf-loop-through-pages-and-add-content

Comment: The second link is dead :(